# Use DropDownList selecteditem in Linq Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist that is a list of columns from a gridview.  I need to be able to populate another dropdownlist based on the selection of the column in the first dropdownlist.  I am populating the first dropdownlist like this:

```
public void ddlColumnPopulate()
    {
        var gvColumns = GridView1.Columns;
        var viewName = ((IDataSource)EntityDataSource1).GetViewNames().OfType<string>().First();

        var view = (EntityDataSourceView)((IDataSource)EntityDataSource1).GetView(viewName);
        var schema = view.GetViewSchema();
        var dsColumns = schema.Columns;
        var dvColumnsDict = gvColumns.OfType<BoundField>().ToDictionary(a => a.DataField);


        foreach (DataColumn c in dsColumns)
        {
            //var li = new ListItem(string.Format("{0}: {1}", c.ColumnName, c.DataType), c.DataType.ToString());  
            var li = new ListItem(c.ColumnName,  c.DataType.ToString());
            ddlColumn.Items.Add(li);                  

        }            
    }
```

I'm trying to populate the second dropdownlist like this, but it's not working.  I'm not sure if you can even do something like this?

```
public void populatecolumn()
    {
         using (TestEntities dbContext = new TestEntities())
         {

             string col = ddlColumn.SelectedItem.ToString();

             var a = (from b in dbContext.tbl_Batch                          
                      select col);

             ddlData.DataSource = a;
             ddlData.DataTextField = col;
             ddlData.DataValueField = col;
             DataBind();

             ddlData.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
             ddlData.SelectedIndex = 0; 

         }           
    }
```

I'm getting the error message:  DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'intBatchID'.

Answer (score 0):

change your
`var a = (from b in dbContext.tbl_Batch

                      select col);`

to 
`var a = (from b in dbContext.tbl_Batch

                      select col).tolist();`

Comment: and what's the content of a and col?

Comment: I dont know what's the content of your a. but it seems your a is string and not a list. if your a have intBatchID you should not have problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix several things:

Instead of `SelectedItem.ToString()` you have to use `SelectedItem.Text`:

```
string col = ddlColumn.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Your need to fix `linq` query as well. You will need to use System.Linq.Dynamic
to pass the column name to the linq query. You will need reflection to get the column data also. The following should work, but I would appreciate any modification :

**EDIT :** 
 You need to use `System.Linq.Dynamic`, not `Dynamic Expression API`.

```
string col = ddlColumn.SelectedItem.Text;   
string selColName = "new(" + col + ")";

var q = dbContext.tbl_Batch.Select(selColName);

List<string> myList = new List<string>();

foreach (var colItem in q)
{
    if (colItem != null)
    {

        Type type = colItem.GetType();
        PropertyInfo pInfo = type.GetProperty(col);
        var myValue = pInfo.GetValue(colItem, null);
        myList.Add(myValue.ToString());
    }
}
myList = myList.Select(x => x).Distinct().ToList();
ddlData.DataSource = myList;
ddlData.DataBind();
```

You have to install <strike>`Dynamic Expression API`</strike>  `System.Linq.Dynamic` (avaiable in `Nuget`) and add the following:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Reflection;
```

You can downloadmy test project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0WGg5dktRTkw5MmM/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: I'm getting an error on the linq - Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: when it gets to foreach I'm getting the error message: 'new' cannot be resolved into a valid type or function. Near simple identifier, line 1, column 8.

Comment: is item and colitem supposed to be the same variable?

Comment: It should be colItem... forgot to change variable name everywhere after testing it. SelectedValue should be SelectedItem. I have fixed the code.

Comment: I'm still getting the error message:'new' cannot be resolved into a valid type or function. Near simple identifier, line 1, column 8. When I hit foreach.  I'm not sure what the error means?

Comment: Please make sure you have installed expression api and added referemce to system.linq.dynamic.

Comment: Can you add .Where(x=> true) like this: `var q = dbContext.tbl_Batch.Where(x=> true).Select(selColName);` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44732/discussion-between-hollyquinn-and-afzalulh)

Comment: I did.  I thought it was going to work until it got to DataBind();  And I got this error message.  DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'intBatchID'.  That seems to be the error I get no matter how it is coded.

Comment: @hollyquinn - edited my answer. Actually, you have to add linq.dynamic, not expression. I have added a link to my test project as well at the bottom of the answer.